# Evil moon: Part 1 - The explanation

Tags: science-based, biology, vision

**Man in the Moon**

As humans we have a built-in tendency to see faces in random patterns. On Earth we have a "man-in-the-moon"

[image]

Image by Luc Viatour. - Original by Luc Viatour, edited by The Man in Question. Variation on this image by Weeneldo., CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=50740927

---

**Evil moon**

On a far-away planet, aliens also have a face on the moon but unfortunately it looks almost exactly like the face of a very unpleasant predator (You don't want to know the details!)

**Question**

Biologically and physically speaking, this could just be a random coincidence but I'd like a plausible reason that the predator looks like the moon or the the moon looks like the predator. Can you come up with a good explanation that is scientifically possible?

---

Comment: For the same reason that people on Earth believe that the darker areas on our Moon form a human face?

Comment: @AlexP - Yes that's possible but infants are born being able to recognise human faces. It is a built-in pattern-recognition instinct. They have to learn what other creatures look like. Even when they do, there is a tendency to humanise the faces - https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/01/08/37/animal-1298839_960_720.png  - You have a point though.

Comment: Lol your pareidolia needs help! ;D

Answer (score 1):

**Ancient Civilization Propoganda**

Let's think about this logically. If the moon looks exactly like a predator, that means that something or someone made it *look* like the predator, assuming we rule out random chance. Now, given that the predator is native to the planet, that means that someone from the planet did it, which in turn suggests that there was an ancient technologically advanced civilization which fell to ruin which once possessed the ability to go to the moon and terraform it. Now, you can see the moon every night so there are only two reasonable explanations as to why you would want to terraform the moon to look like something. The first is advertising, unlikely given the fact that they chose the predator as their symbol and no multinational corporation which would have the ability to do so would pick a predator as their logo. (Earth's multinational corporations tend to have friendlier logos. It's the smaller and more niche companies which go for predator logos.) The second is propaganda - perhaps there were two warring countries and one, for propaganda effects, carved their country's symbol, the mighty predator, into the moon. That, or it was a publicity stunt from a sports team.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas:

- **Inducing copulation.** [A certain species of coral](https://www.livescience.com/37927-how-moon-affects-nocturnal-animals.html) releases large amounts of sperm and eggs on a night when the moon is brightest. Perhaps your predator preys on a species that is induced to mate by the full moon. By imitating the full moon (with its face), your predator fools its prey into coming out of hiding.
- **Camouflage.** (This idea only works if your predator is airborne.) Having a face/body that looks like the moon could be useful for a flying predator. When its prey looks up in the air, it will see what it *thinks* is just the moon and assume that it is safe. Then the predator will swoop in for the kill.
- **Defense.** Perhaps an alien civilization on your planet once worshipped the moon. The predator’s moon-like face is actually an adaptation to *prevent hunters from killing it*, since the aliens considered the moon sacred and would refuse to kill an animal resembling it.